# Nikon D800 Intervalometer Issue

Tags: nikon, intervalometer, nikon-d800

I'm using my D800, and I've come across an issue, when I use the "Interval Shooting Mode", and use the following settings: 1/100th, f8, ISO 320, the camera disregards the interval of 5 seconds when Interval Shooting begins and is shooting at Continuous High. Switching the camera to CL (Continuous Low), Quiet or any other modes doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You're very specific about the camera exposure settings. Does the intervalometer operate properly with any other settings?

Comment: How many shots per interval have you selected? The bottom should say something like `003 x 2 = 0006` where `003` is the number of intervals, `2` is the shots per interval, and `0006` is the total number of shots.